# Securing a single API GET request from within Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, api

Sorry in advance if this will be a stupid question.

**My situation**

I have a simple web app where a user has to log in before he can access any other page. Once the user is signed in he gets redirected to a dashboard that, every minute, makes an axios ajax GET request to an API link from within my application.

So to clarify, Page '/' makes javascript calls to '/api/example' every minute.

**My problem**

I'm new to API's and I need this link to *only* be accessible to logged in users from *my application only*. I've made the mistake to invest my time into Laravel Passport only to realize that it's probably slightly 'overkill' *and* completely unnecessary as I don't need other applications to access that API link. It merely serves as a database call method to fill the dashboard with data.

**My question**

As this is but a simple site with a single API GET url, how can I properly secure that link so that it's only accessible by the signed-in users? Would JWT be a more proper approach?

Thank you.

Comment: If your route is in api.php  then write your route in `Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
 //your protected route here });`

Answer (score 0):

If your route is in `api.php` then write your routes in

```
 Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() { 
    //your protected routes here 
 });
```

**If your route is in web.php then:**

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function() { 
    //your protected routes here 
 });
```

User will not be able to access routes written in `auth or auth:api` middleware until logged in